# Estimating the smallest distance between $n$ points uniformly distributed on the unit circle.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working on the following question and would like some hints or solutions

> Let $n$ points be iid, uniformly distributed on the unit circle. Let
>   $\Delta_n$ be the smallest distance between any two of these points. 
>   Show that $n^\theta \Delta_n\to 0$ in probability as $n\to \infty$, for all $0<\theta<2$. HINT: Divide the circle into small arcs and find the probability that at
>   least one arc contains 2 or more points

So I tried following the hint, and I considered dividing up the circle into $n-1$ pieces that would give with probability 1, that two are in the same section.  However, $n^\theta/n-1$ does not go to zero.    The other things I tried were $n^2$ pieces and $n$ pieces, but the probability calculations are rather messy for these and I'd be dealing with factorials, which does not seem like it would go well with this problem.

[Source: Problem 2](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/S16_Probability_507a.pdf)

Comment: Try starting with the following question.  Given n points and m (> n) arcs, what is the probability that all the points are in different arcs?  The answer to your question should follow.

Comment: I got that the probability is $\frac{m*(m-1)\cdots(m-n+1)}{m^n}$ but don't we need to be more specific about what $m$ is becuase $n^\theta/m$ doesnt necessarily go to zero.

Comment: Can you make something of the following?  In the limit, we are essentially dealing with points distributed according to a Poisson distribution with mean separation $2\pi/n$.  Then the minimum of $n$ variables, each with that distribution, has a mean value of $1/n$ times that, or $2\pi/n^2$, and the result follows.  Not exactly rigorous, but perhaps it can be turned into something rigorous.

Comment: Also, with the factorials, I'd make use of Stirling's approximation, if that's permissible.

Comment: I think stirling's approximation is fair game here, since we did indeed cover it in class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), thinly disguised.  (I'm a little dismayed it took me this long to see it.)  If we divide the circle into $m$ equal segments, then the probability that there exists at least one segment shared by at least two of the $n$ points is $q = 1-\frac{m!}{m^n(m-n)!}$.  [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)—

$$
k! \approx \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k\sqrt{2\pi k}
$$

—[allows us to rewrite](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/TheBirthdayParadox.html) $q$, roughly, as

$$
q \approx 1-\exp \left(-\frac{n^2}{2m}\right)
$$

Observe that for $m = n^\theta$, $0 < \theta < 2$, we have that $q \approx 1-\exp \left(\frac{-n^{2-\theta}}{2}\right) \to 1$.

The Wikipedia article linked above gives a variety of ways to approximate the birthday coincidence probability.  Pick a favorite. :-)

Comment: Thanks, the idea makes sense but I'm trying to work out the details and I seem to be getting stuck.  For instance, how do you get that $\frac{m!}{m^n(m-n)!}$ equals $\exp(-n/m^2)$.  Using stirling's approximation, I'm getting that it is $e^{(-n)}(\frac{m}{m-n})^{(m-n+1/2)}$, but I don't see how to further simplify it.   Also, there might be a typo somewhere because if you set $m=n^\theta$, we would have $\exp{(-n^{1-2\theta})}$, not $\exp{(-n^{2-\theta})}$.

Comment: @iYOA: Yeah, that was a whopper of a typo.  I edited my answer, but you can check the edit history.

Comment: @iYOA: To answer your other question, see [here](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/TheBirthdayParadox.html) for a pretty good exposition.  It's about halfway down the page—look for "Stirling."